# Django Deployment of static files

Tags: django

In my setting file (jantiyes.settings.production) I have the following declaration:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ymorin007/webapps/jantiyes_static/'
```

But when I run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

I get the following message:

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /home/ymorin007/tmp/tmp1ukao3g8
```

How can I fix the destination to be the STATIC_ROOT I declared?

**Just to let you know**

- This is my first collectstatic experience on this application.
- I've double check and the folder /home/ymorin007/webapps/jantiyes_static does exist.
- I've restarted the server.

**my manage.py file**

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "jantiyes.settings.production")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: In the console where you run `python manage.py collectstatic`, make sure the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is set correctly before calling collectstatic: i.e. `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=jantiyes.settings.production; python manage.py collectstatic`.

Comment: Still the same tmp folder

Comment: Ah, I see you've added your `manage.py` file which makes my first comment obsolete. What does your deployment look like? Are you using something like `buildout` or `virtualenv`?

Comment: Yes I use virtualenv

Comment: Please confirm you've activated your `virtualenv` before calling collecstatic. Is it just `STATIC_ROOT` that's not correctly loaded? Or do you have trouble loading (for example) database settings as well?

Comment: Yes I'm in the virtualenv and I've run python manage.py makemigrations
successfully. Only seems to be the STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67765/discussion-between-bjorn-and-yannick).

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Debug = True and it works now.

Sorry.